# I added and deleted an app widget but i am still getting errors from its values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, widget, android-widget

I added a widget to my app. Then i deleted its files. It seems there is no widgets in my app now. But then i realized there is more file about widgets. Such as "app_widget_background.xml" in drawable or "attrs.xml" in values, "styles (v21)" and "styles (v31)" in styles. I cant delete them because app is crashing like that;

```
Android resource linking failed
com.ahmetkaan.kediy.app-mergeDebugResources-75:/values-v21/values-v21.xml:556: error: resource drawable/app_widget_background (aka com.ahmetkaan.kediy:drawable/app_widget_background) not found.
com.ahmetkaan.kediy.app-mergeDebugResources-75:/values-v21/values-v21.xml:556: error: resource drawable/app_widget_background (aka com.ahmetkaan.kediy:drawable/app_widget_background) not found.
com.ahmetkaan.kediy.app-mergeDebugResources-75:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:369: error: resource drawable/app_widget_background (aka com.ahmetkaan.kediy:drawable/app_widget_background) not found.
com.ahmetkaan.kediy.app-mergeDebugResources-75:/values-v31/values-v31.xml:369: error: resource drawable/app_widget_background (aka com.ahmetkaan.kediy:drawable/app_widget_background) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

This an error code when i get because of deleting "app_widget_background.xml". How can i figure this out?

Comment: `find . -name values-v31.xml`